# Is this a sloppy point in Brezis' construction of topology generated by a family of subsets?

Tags: general-topology

I'm reading **Section 3.1** *The Coarsest Topology for Which a Collection of Maps Becomes Continuous* from Brezis's *Functional Analysis*:

> **Problem 2.** Given a set $X$ and a family $(U_{\lambda})_{\lambda \in \Lambda}$ of subsets in $X$, construct the cheapest topology $\mathscr{T}$ on $X$ in which $U_{\lambda}$ is open for all $\lambda \in \Lambda$.

In other words, we must find the cheapest family $\mathscr{F}$ of subsets of $X$ that is stable$^1$ by $\cap_{\text {finite}}$ and $\cup_{\text {arbitrary}}$ and with the property that $U_{\lambda} \in \mathscr{F}$ for every $\lambda \in \Lambda$. The construction goes as follows.

- First, consider finite intersections of sets in $(U_{\lambda})_{\lambda \in \Lambda}$, i.e., $\cap_{\lambda \in \Gamma} U_{\lambda}$ where $\Gamma \subset \Lambda$ is finite. In this way we obtain a new family, called $\Phi$, of subsets of $X$ which includes $(U_{\lambda})_{\lambda \in \Lambda}$ and which is stable under $\cap_{\text {finite}}$. However, it need not be stable under $\cup_{\text {arbitrary}}$.
- Therefore, we consider next the family $\mathscr{F}$ obtained by forming arbitrary unions of elements from $\Phi$. It is clear that $\mathscr{F}$ is stable under $\cup_{\text {arbitrary}}$. It is not clear whether $\mathscr{F}$ is stable under $\cap_{\text {finite}}$; but indeed we have the following result:

> **Lemma 3.1.** The family $\mathscr{F}$ is stable under $\cap_{\text {finite}}$.

The proof of Lemma 3.1-a delightful exercise in set theory-is left to the reader; see e.g., **G. Folland [2]**. It is now obvious that the above construction gives the cheapest topology with the required property.

${ }^{1}$ Meaning that a finite intersection of sets in $\mathscr{F}$ and an arbitrary union of sets in $\mathscr{F}$ both belong to $\mathscr{F}$.

---

Below is the cross reference from **G. Folland [2]**: Let $X$ be a set and $\mathcal S$ a collection of subsets of $X$. Let $\tau(\mathcal S)$ be the smallest topology on $X$ that contains $\mathcal S$.

> **Theorem:**  Then $\tau (\mathcal S)$ consists of $\varnothing, X$, and all unions of finite intersections of members of $\mathcal{S}$.
>
> *Proof (by Folland):* The family of finite intersections of sets in $\mathcal S$, together with $X$, is a base for some topology $\tau'$ on $X$, so the family of all unions of such sets, together with $\varnothing$, is ineed the topology $\tau'$. Obviously, $\tau'$ is contained in $\tau (\mathcal S)$, hence equal to $\tau (\mathcal S)$.

---

**My question:**

According to Folland, we have to "manually" include $X$ into $\tau (\mathcal S)$, i.e., it is possible that $X$ is different from the union of all finite intersections of sets in $\mathcal S$.

Let $\Gamma_0 = \emptyset \subset \Lambda$. By usual convention, we have $\cap_{\lambda \in \Lambda_0} U_{\lambda} = \emptyset$. However, it seems to me that $\mathscr{T}$ (obtained from Brezis' construction) does not necceassily contain $X$. Then $\mathscr{T}$ is **not** neccesasily a topology on $X$.

> Could you confirm if my understanding is correct?

Comment: Unless I missed something, I think your observation is correct. Every element of $\mathscr{F}$ is a subset of the union of all the $U_{\lambda}$'s, which may be a proper subset of $X$. As you suggest, one need to manually include $X$ into $\mathscr{F}$ in order to fix this small issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Yes and no.**

It's not sloppy because you don't actually need to define a topology to explicitly contain the empty set and the whole space. It is **typical** for authors to demand that within the definition but, strictly speaking, it's not necessary. The reason for that is due to the following formulas:

1. $\bigcup \varnothing = \varnothing$.
2. $\bigcap \varnothing = X$.

Now, there's a caveat with that second formula which I'll need to get to so just wait for that. The first formula should be quite easy to understand; if I know my proposed set $\tau(S)$ is closed under arbitrary unions, then I can just take an empty subset of $\tau(S)$ and take the union of that. This will automatically mean that $\varnothing \in \tau(S)$.

The issue with that second statement is that, implicitly, we're taking the intersection of the empty set within $X$ itself. It's only in this case that the formula actually makes sense. Otherwise, you actually have the following theorem.

**Theorem:**
Let $x$ be any set. Then, $x \in \bigcap \varnothing$.

**Proof:**
Otherwise, there exists a $y \in \varnothing$ such that $x \notin y$. But this is impossible. $\Box$

But if you make it clear that you're only considering the intersection of the empty set within $X$ itself, then it's all good. In that case, the fact that $X \in \tau(S)$ will just follow from the fact that it is closed under finite intersections.

With all of that being said, I do think that he is being sloppy because I don't think that the above is really what he might've been thinking of. I don't think that the above is what occurred to him when he didn't explicitly state that the entire set belongs to your collection.